# Step-3 is skipping from virtuemart 4-steps checkout

Tags: php, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I'm frustrated of VM bug. My Joomla has VM, which has checkout 1, checkout 2(shipping), checkout 3(payment selection) and checkout 4, where everything is sequentially working fine, but checkout 3 is skipping, means, moving directly from checkout 2 to checkout 4. Even reverse of it is also working fine. What could be the problem for this? I'm using Joomla 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Please check these two settings in your Virtuemart:

> Configuration -> Checkout -> One Page Checkout enabled [disabled]
>
> Configuration -> Checkout -> Enable Automatic Selected Payment
> [disabled]

Comment: Thank you very much emmanuel.. It has worked. I've spent long time to figure out this bug. But nothing has paid off finally. Emmanuel, another bug has erupted from this. In Step-3, it is showing only default payment, is not showing remaining payment options. What could be the problem. Once again thank you emmanuel..

Comment: Nice to hear that, you are welcome! As for the rest payments please check the settings of each payment if you have added limits that has to be removed.

Comment: Emmanuel.. all credentials are right. I'm using Paypal as one among rest of payments. Everything displaying fine except paypal. But when i remove country "canada" from Countries option under paypal method configuration settings then it is being displayed fine. If i add it again then paypal option on front-end is disappearing. Pls help me..

Comment: Please try to remove all countries from selection (to work for all) and if it doesn't solve your problem try to update virtuemart to the latest version.

Comment: Thank you Emmanuel. It's working perfectly fine. If i use any country apart from canada then it's working fine. Now i have removed all county list & left it empty, working everything fine. But i want to make sure that, it won't make any bad impact in future, if i make it empty.. right.. As i'm new-bee to VM. so please don't mind.. Your answer has helped me a lot.. THank you once again.. emmanuel

Comment: Empty list mean that won't restrict any country so it is just fine. You are welcome!